# How do I call a method from a different class on an existing object (Obj C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm very new to Objective C and Xcode and could just be doing something stupid wrong, but I have tried a lot of different suggestions and can't get them to work.

In short, I want to call a method on an existing UIViewController, when a button is pressed in a different UIViewController.

(A bit of background: the two screens are a **main screen** and a **menu screen**. The user swipes up to view the menu, then when the done button is pressed I want the menu screen to send a string variable (URL in this case) to a method in the main screen, and the main screen then displays the URL in a UIWebView).

I have tried putting the method/URL variable in AppDelegate/MainViewController and synthesizing them. I have also tried to make MenuViewController a subclass of MainViewCOntroller and calling the method using [super readFile:url], that did compile but I don't think it called in on the existing MainViewController object, because the webview didn't appear.

I'll paste the relevant bits of my code below: (Thank you for any help!)

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIWebView *vCodeView;
}

- (void)readFile:(NSString *)newURL;

@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)readFile:(NSString *)newURL {
    vCodeView.hidden = NO;

    // seperate url by full stops
    NSArray *splitURL = [newURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    // find extension of file
    NSString *extension = [splitURL objectAtIndex:([splitURL count]-1)];

    // DO SOME OTHER STUFF WITH URL THEN DISPLAY CONTENT IN UIWEBVIEW
}

- (void)swipeUpRecognised {
    MenuViewController *menuView = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    menuView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:menuView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**MenuViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *bDone;
    IBOutlet UITextField *fUser;
    IBOutlet UITextField *fPass;
    IBOutlet UITextField *fAddress;
    IBOutlet UITextField *fAutoConnectAddress;
}

- (IBAction)bDonePressed;

@end
```

**MenuViewController.m**

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuViewController

- (IBAction)bDonePressed {

    NSString *user = @"admin";
    NSString *pass = @"password";
    NSString *path = @"54.246.90.95/repos/project1/trunk/dir1/test.c";

    // url of file
    NSArray *pathArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://", user, @":", pass, @"@", path, nil];
    NSString *url = [pathArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    //call the method here passing in url

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: declare your method in appdelegate.m file than call from your class

Comment: @keyur That's a pretty bad idea. That would have his view controller knowing about methods in his app delegate.

Comment: A small mistake in your implementation: You usually would have `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can put in the following before the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` call, and it should work:

```
if(self.presentingViewController && [self.presentingViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(readFile:)]) {
    [(id)self.presentingViewController readFile:url];
}
```

In general, what you actually want is called [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

So, for a cleaner implementation, try this:

#### MenuViewController.h

```
@protocol MenuViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)menuViewControllerFinishedWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
@end

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController {
    @property id<MenuViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
// ...
```

#### MenuViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)bDonePressed {
    // ...

    if(self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate menuViewControllerFinishedWithURL:url];
    }

    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

#### MainViewController.m

```
@interface MainViewController () <MenuViewControllerDelegate>

@end

// ...

- (void)swipeUpRecognised {
    MenuViewController *menuView = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    menuView.delegate = self;
    menuView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:menuView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've literally been trying different solutions for days! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of calling MainViewController method, it should be easy:

1. Include MainViewController.h into MenuViewController.h.
2. Call this snippet where you want it to:

   ```
   NSString * vcid = @""; //put id you have assigned to your MainViewController. This should be in your storyboard. If it is empty, fill it with proper name, then use it here.
   UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   MainViewController *mainvc =[storybord instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier:vcid];
   [mainvc method];
   ```

Note that `method` must be declared in MainViewController.h file for it to be called.

That said, I wonder if your design of having separate view controller for the menu maybe really needed. If you want to offer some set of buttons to user for the sake of choice, consider a UIView containing all of them. This UIView should then be popped up in your `swipeUpRecognised`.

Comment: Sorry I probably should have mentioned, I'm using .xib's instead of a storyboard. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Even there you should be able to specify this property. Just select view controller and see what your attribute inspector shows you.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you...
Modify your code like this....

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIWebView *vCodeView;
}

- (void)readFile:(NSString *)newURL;

@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)readFile:(NSString *)newURL {
    vCodeView.hidden = NO;

    // seperate url by full stops
    NSArray *splitURL = [newURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    // find extension of file
    NSString *extension = [splitURL objectAtIndex:([splitURL count]-1)];

    // DO SOME OTHER STUFF WITH URL THEN DISPLAY CONTENT IN UIWEBVIEW
}

- (void)swipeUpRecognised {
    MenuViewController *menuView = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
menuView.delegate = self;
    menuView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:menuView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**MenuViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *bDone;
    IBOutlet UITextField *fUser;
    IBOutlet UITextField *fPass;
    IBOutlet UITextField *fAddress;
    IBOutlet UITextField *fAutoConnectAddress;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) MainViewController *delegate;
- (IBAction)bDonePressed;

@end
```

**MenuViewController.m**

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuViewController
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
- (IBAction)bDonePressed {

    NSString *user = @"admin";
    NSString *pass = @"password";
    NSString *path = @"54.246.90.95/repos/project1/trunk/dir1/test.c";

    // url of file
    NSArray *pathArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://", user, @":", pass, @"@", path, nil];
    NSString *url = [pathArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    //call the method here passing in url
    [self.delegate readFile:url];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```